# What is the correct syntax for list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Still somewhat new to python and list comprehension is something i cant seem to find too much about online for some reason.

currently trying to create a list of median averages from a list containing multiple sets of values.

I did have a longer function for it but wanted to make it more simple using list comprehension

```python
# part of an object containing self._rawdata
def get_medians(self):
        medianlist = [sets[len(sets)//2-1] for sets in self._rawdata if not len(sets)%2 \
                      else (sets[len(sets)//2 - 2] + sets[len(sets)//2 -1])/2 for sets in self._rawdata]
        return medianlist
```

I get Invalid Syntax error and it highlights 'else', what would be the correct syntax to use?

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension for that. Just use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You put the condition in the wrong place.

Try out your loop as a regular loop first, I *think* you wanted to do this:

```
for sets in self._rawdata:
    if not len(sets)%2:
        sets[len(sets)//2-1]
    else:
        (sets[len(sets)//2 - 2] + sets[len(sets)//2 -1]) / 2
```

where the two `sets` expressions are the values you want to add to your resulting list.

The `if ... else ...` statement can be collapsed using a conditional expression, allowing you to put the whole thing in a list comprehension:

```
[sets[len(sets)//2-1] if not len(sets)%2 else (sets[len(sets)//2 - 2] + sets[len(sets)//2 -1]) / 2
 for sets in self._rawdata]
```

So for every `sets` in the loop, you produce one of two expressions based on the `not len(sets)%2` test.

It might have been easier had you delegated picking the median to a function:

```
def median(sets):
    if not len(sets) % 2:
        return sets[len(sets)//2-1]
    return (sets[len(sets)//2 - 2] + sets[len(sets)//2 -1]) / 2
```

and used that in your list comprehension:

```
[median(sets) for sets in self._rawdata]
```

which is a lot more readable.

Comment: You are correct and that is the previous code i had written which works.
list comprehension just saves me a few lines, and the ordering fixed it so thanks